# OpenFlow switching based on a specific ethertype

Tags: ethernet, openflow, tap

My goal is to send to a specific interface all ethernet traffic with a special ethertype. I have thus a virtual switch with `OpenVSwitch` on my interface `eth0`, and I use tap interfaces to retrieve specific frames in order to process them. The normal flow is sent to `tap1`, while the special flow is sent to `tap0`. Here is the OpenVSwitch configuration:

```
# ovs-vsctl show
44c95237-25bd-45fd-bb97-d596aecf5f46
Bridge brLan
    Port "tap0"
        Interface "tap0"
    Port "tap1"
        Interface "tap1"
    Port eth0
        Interface eth0
    Port brLan
        Interface brLan
            type: internal
ovs_version: "2.5.0"
```

On the bridge `brLan`, with 3 ports (`eth0`, `tap0`, and `tap1`), I'd like to switch all frames with ethertype = `0x88B5` to `tap0`, while all other frames are going though `tap1`.

I made thus these OpenFlow rules:

```
# ovs-ofctl add-flow brLan "idle_timeout=0,priority=33100,in_port=1,dl_type=0x88b5,actions=output:6"
# ovs-ofctl add-flow brLan "idle_timeout=0,priority=33100,in_port=1,actions=output:7"
```

where `6` is the ID of `tap0` and `7` is the ID of `tap1`, displayed with `# ovs-ofctl show brLan`

Now, if I send the frames to this interface `eth0` with the ethertype `0x88B5`, they aren't switched to `tap0`, as shows the command:

```
# ovs-ofctl dump-flows brLan
NXST_FLOW reply (xid=0x4):
cookie=0x0, duration=54229.821s, table=0, n_packets=27269, n_bytes=1636190, idle_age=0, priority=33100,in_port=1 actions=output:7
cookie=0x0, duration=54229.790s, table=0, n_packets=0, n_bytes=0, idle_age=54229, priority=33100,in_port=1,dl_type=0x88b5 actions=output:6
```

The first flow is the normal flow of usual ethernet frames, and I see it's OK, well switched to tap1. But about the flow to `output:6`, no frames arrive, *even though I can display them using WireShark!*

Any ideas on how to solve this, to make the switching of frames with ether_type = `0x88B5` arrive to `tap0`?

Comment: Do I have to install a custom classifier on openvswitch ? These machines are on a completety separated network.

Comment: just curious, why are you doing this?  Openflow/SDN I mean?  What is the application?

Comment: To bind specific programs to thses taps, in order to handles specific pakets ;)

Comment: I ask because I am curious what consumers are using SDN for.  I understand it's application in OEM's / manufacturers of networking products, but not by end users.  In fact, I have no idea what a tap is!  As I understand it, programs/applications can be bound/configured to use to protocols and ports such as TCP port 25 (SMTP).  I've never heard of taps.

Comment: I'm not an end user ;) I'm designing networking products. And if the products don't fully rely on an IP stack, you can't use TCP ports. Besides, using Raw sockets are a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the priorities given to the flows.

As the 2 flows look into the **same** port (`eth0`), they **have to** have different priorities.

Setting the first flow to :

```
# ovs-ofctl add-flow brLan "idle_timeout=0,priority=44100,in_port=1,dl_type=0x88b5,actions=output:6"
```

This solved the problem